# ActionFilterAttribute - apply to actions of a specific controller type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm using an ActionFilterAttribute to do custom authentication logic.  The Attribute will only be used on a derived Controller class that contains my authentication logic.

Here's my Controller, derived from my custom controller class, and a sample attribute:

```
public class MyController : CustomControllerBase
{

   [CustomAuthorize(UserType = UserTypes.Admin)]
   public ActionResult DoSomethingSecure()
   {
      return View();
   }

}
```

Here's an example of my ActionFilterAttribute:

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
   public MyUserTypes UserType { get; set; }

   public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
   {
      myUser user = ((CustomControllerBase)filterContext.Controller).User;

      if(!user.isAuthenticated)
      {
         filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
      }
   }
}
```

Works great.

**Here's the question:** Can I demand that this attribute ONLY be used on Actions in my custom controller type?

Comment: Your attribute is broken because it doesn't inherit from AuthroizeAttribute and thus is not guaranteed to run when the action is cached. See http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/09/09/38390/ for solutions which work with caching.

Comment: Why would the action result be cached?

Comment: It would be cached because someone told it to be cached. Imagine someone puts the Cache attribute on a parent class, not noticing the broken attribute on the subtype. It's a far better idea to use an attribute which is not fundamentally incompatible with ASP.NET/MVC caching. See the link above for options.

Comment: @Craig - Good catch. I didn't actually look at the action filter itself. He's correct - if you write your own authorization action filter, you really should inherit from AuthorizeAttribute. Then, you can override the AuthorizeCore() protected method.

Comment: You've convinced me that AuthorizeAttribute is the way to go.  Unfortunately, AuthorizeCore has access to HttpContext instead of ActionExecutingContext.  Because of this, I no longer have access to the underlying Controller, so I lose access to the "myUser" member of the controller in my example.

Comment: Iconic, that's because *the action may not be running* when authorization needs bo be checked. Again, consider a cached action result. You cannot make any authorization scheme which depends on a controller work, ever.

Comment: Craig, thanks for explaining...I now understand the problem, but am reluctant to refactor since other areas of the application (that aren't cached) rely on the quasi-authorization logic in the controller.  Since caching is the concern, would it be possible to simply override OnActionExecuted() and and set Response.Cache.SetNoServerCaching(), Response.Cache.SetNoStore(), and Response.DisableKernelCache() ?

Comment: It is possible run those methods in OnActionExecuted...I meant to say "is it advisable."

Comment: Disabling caching fixes the problem in the same way decapitation cures acne. :) Just do it the other way around. Instead of OnActionExecuting *getting* the user from the controller, you can have a subtype of AuthorizeAction *set* the user in the controller in an override of the OnAuthorization method (filterContext.Controller). Then the code in the controllers will still work as it did before.

Comment: See my "answer."  Seems to do the job.

Comment: Needs some clarification on this topic here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441799/authorization-and-asp-net-mvc-caching

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can put the ActionFilter on the class itself. All actions in the class will realize the ActionFilter.

```
[CustomAuthorize]
public class AuthorizedControllerBase : CustomControllerBase
{
}

public class OpenAccessControllerBase : CustomControllerBase
{
}

public class MyRealController : AuthorizedControllerBase 
{
    // GET: /myrealcontroller/index
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm just going the route of defining the ActionFilter within the class (so it is not available on other classes.)  It's good to know that the attribute can be defined across ALL ActionResults in a controller.

Answer (score 7):

Based on the comments and the constraints of my system, I took a hybrid approach.  Basically, if the request comes through via a cached route or the "User" is not set for any reason, authentication fails in the proper way.

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
  private MyUser User { get; set; }

  public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
  {
    //Lazy loads the user in the controller.
    User = ((MyControllerBase)filterContext.Controller).User;

    base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
  }

  protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
  {
    bool isAuthorized = false;
    string retLink = httpContext.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;

    if(User != null)
    {
      isAuthorized = User.IsValidated;
    }

    if (!isAuthorized)
    {
      //If the current request is coming in via an AJAX call,
      //simply return a basic 401 status code, otherwise, 
      //redirect to the login page.
      if (httpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
      {
        httpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
      }
      else
      {
        httpContext.Response.Redirect("/login?retlink=" + retLink);
      }
    }

    return isAuthorized;
  }
}
```

Comment: If you are redirecting in any "isAuthorized=false" case, then why don't you just return true at the end?

Comment: In the case of the IsAjaxRequest flow, the user is not redirected, so the method still needs to return.

Comment: +1 for using AuthorizeAttribute instead of ActionFilterAttribute. Solves the problem that the controller action that has the CustomAuthotize attribute is executed even if we're not logged in which may cause other problems.