# MVC 4 Mobile Template Redirect To Action fails after post

Tags: jquery, c#-4.0, jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-4, beta

I'm using the MVC 4.0 mobile template for a project and I run into an odd problem with the default scaffolding/template. 
I created a simple model:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

then I created a simple Controller with an Index action and a Create action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
        return View(persons);
    }

public ActionResult Create()
    {
        Person p = new Person();
        return View(p);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Person/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Person p)
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add insert logic here
            //empty

            //return Redirect("/Person/Index");
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Person", null);
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Generated the views for the two actions: for Index I generated a List view and for the Create I generated a Create view. Now the problem is that after I create a new product it should redirect to Index view which in an odd way it does but the url remains /Person/Create and then when I click the 'Create New' link on the Index view nothing happens. (create new link as it was generated:  @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create") )

I'm thinking this is a bug but I didn't found anything online yet..
Any recommendations as to how I can make this work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a workaround: [jQuery Mobile/MVC: Getting the browser URL to change with RedirectToAction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824243/jquery-mobile-mvc-getting-the-browser-url-to-change-with-redirecttoaction)

Additionally, the page was not refreshing (I used IE) so I had to follow this answer in order to get the page to be refreshed on IE after `RedirectToAction`: [How to stop MVC caching the results of invoking an action method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969450/how-to-stop-mvc-caching-the-results-of-invoking-an-action-method)