# How to Get New updates from page in a website while requesting?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7

I have  frequently  change a page in my web application per day or per week.  while requsting that page via browser, i will get only old updates . so For get to render new updates in that page, i need to refresh that page several times.

Can you please suggest any logic to render my wepapge with latest changes while requesting that page in Programatical  way? i have developed my wep app using ASP.NET MVC3.0 platform.

(or)
 if any changes , we need to make in IIS server[website host server].

Please suggest is this process possible to do in wep app?

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly tell a browser not to cache the result of an action by placing the following code in the action:

```
HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
```

A more elegant solution is to place this into a attribute you can decorate the action with, as detailed in the top answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969450/how-to-stop-mvc-caching-the-results-of-invoking-an-action-method).