# Session is null in Custom AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session

I have an asp.net MVC application, using framework 4.6, and I create a custom AuthorizeAttribute. In my class I override the AuthorizeCore method and I access the session to verify some authentication informations. But sometimes when I try to access the property session in the AuthorizeCore method I have a NullReferenceException because the session property is null.

The problem is intermittent and it occurs when I have simultaneous access in the same action. If I open the page and refresh the page several times (F5 in browser) it shows the error.

I noticed that when the session is null, the handler is null too.

I am using StateServer mode to store my session. I try to change to InProc mode and I have the same issue. I don't know if it makes difference but I am using Ninject MVC.

My custom attribute:

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContextBase)
        {
            if (!httpContextBase.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return false;
            }

            var infoUser = httpContextBase.Session["infoUser"];

            ...
        }
}
```

My controller:

```
public class HomeController
{
        [CustomAuthorize]
        [OutputCache(CacheProfile = CACHE_PRINCIPAL)]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at this explanation about Membership provider, Session provider and caching:

[Authorization and ASP.NET MVC Caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441799/authorization-and-asp-net-mvc-caching)

Do you use caching?

Comment: Yes, I was using OutputCache. I removed and it works fine.