# .NET Core Action Filter is not a an attribute class

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have this action filter that I want to call, I have already declared it in Startup.cs. However, when I call it above my class, I get this error:

> LogUserNameFilter is not an attribute class

I'm not sure what I'm missing.

```
public class LogUserNameFilter : IActionFilter
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    public LogUserNameFilter(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        LogContext.PushProperty("UserName", context.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
services.AddScoped<LogUserNameFilter>();
```

Class declaration

```
[LogUserNameFilter]
public class HomeController : Controller{


}
```

Comment: Have you tried implementing it as [in this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440121/actionfilterattribute-apply-to-actions-of-a-specific-controller-type)? That is, inheriting `ActionFilterAttribute` instead of implementing `IActionFilter` interface.

Comment: Check [the documentation to see how to implement a filter attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/filter?view=aspnetcore-2.2#implement-a-filter-attribute). That being said, you are mixing code [from your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53867490/216074) here. There is no request delegate in filters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to use a class as an attribute, the class should inherit the `Attribute` class, specifically in your case, you should inherit `ActionFilterAttribute`:

```
public class LogUserNameFilter : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    public LogUserNameFilter(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        LogContext.PushProperty("UserName", context.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
    }
}
```

You can find more use information in [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2#implementation)

Comment: You won’t be able to instantiate this class as an attribute.

Comment: @poke, why is it needed to instantiate that class?

Comment: If you do `[MyAttribute]` then that attribute is instantiated. And in order to instantiate it, it needs a constructor with only constant value arguments. You won’t be able to pass a `RequestDelegate` to `[LogUserNameFilter(…)]` here.

Comment: @Ofiris poke is rigth. how do you think you will use this filter. Do you have an example

Comment: Ofiris solution is correct except that you don't need to implement IActionFilter as you are already inheriting from ActionFilterAttribute class. 
ActionFilterAttribute class itself implements IActionFilter interface